# Find all $x\in\mathbb R$ that satisfy the equation $|x| − |x − 1| = 1/2$ . Sketch the graph of the equation $y = |x| − |x − 1|$

Tags: real-numbers, piecewise-continuity

So I understand that given $|x|$, it will be in the form $|x|= \{-x: \text{if } x<0\}$ or $|x|= \{x: \text{if } x >= 0\}$. Also, I know that $|x-1| = \{-(x-1): \text{if } x-1 <0 \text{ or } x<1\}$ and $|x-1|= \{(x-1):\text{if } x >= 0 \text{ or } x >= 1\}$.

From here I have no idea how to combine these two equations to a function that could be plotted as a piecewise function, and I do not understand how to combine the boundaries since I am also confused about the negative sign in front of $|x − 1|$ and if it has an effect on the boundary.

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

Consider cases:

Figure out the expression of $|x|-|x-1|$ when

- case $1$: $x < 0$, find expression $f_1$
- case $2$: $0 \le x < 1$, find expression $f_2$.
- case $3$: $x \ge 1$, find expression $f_3$.

For each case, consider whether it can be equal to $\frac12$.

$$|x|-|x-1|=\begin{cases} f_1(x) , & x<0 \\ f_2(x) & 0 \le x < 1 \\ f_3(x) &, x \ge 1\end{cases}$$

Comment: How do I bring these equations together to form a piece wise function?

Comment: I edited the answer.

Comment: ah, it should have been $1$. sorry for the mistake.

Comment: So i found that case 1 and case 3 were not equal to 1/2, in other words it has no solution. So How am i suppose to write f1(x) and f3(x)?

Comment: and f2(x)=  2 x - 1  = 1/2

Comment: For $f_1$ and $f_3$ write down whatever you have? you have proved that there is no solution when $x<0$ and $x \ge 1$.  Now that you obtained $f_1, f_2, f_3$, you can sketch the graph.

Answer (score 0):

Using Mathematica

```
Reduce[Abs[x] - Abs[x - 1] == 1/2, x, Reals]

(* x == 3/4 *)
```

With `ContourPlot`  (http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html)

```
ContourPlot[Abs[x] - Abs[x - 1] == y,
 {x, -5, 5}, {y, -3/2, 3/2},
 MaxRecursion -> 5,
 FrameLabel -> Automatic,
 Epilog -> {Red, Dashed,
   Line[{{-5, 1/2}, {3/4, 1/2}, {3/4, -3/2}}]},
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image]

With `Piecewise` (http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html)

```
Reduce[Abs[x] - Abs[x - 1] == y, x, Reals]
```

[image]

```
y[x_] = Piecewise[{{-1, x <= 0}, {2 x - 1, 0 < x < 1}, {1, x >= 1}}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[y[x], {x, -5, 5},
 PlotRange -> {-3/2, 3/2},
 Frame -> True, Axes -> False,
 FrameLabel -> Automatic,
 Epilog -> {Red, Dashed,
   Line[{{-5, 1/2}, {3/4, 1/2}, {3/4, -3/2}}]}]
```

[image]